# What Is the Difference between Parseval's Theorem and Plancherel Theorem?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform

Wikipedia gives Parseval's theorem as follows. [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)

[image]  ,   [image]  is the Fourier transform of x(t).

And Plancheral's theorem is given as

[image],

where [image] is the fourier analog.

[Plancheral theorem wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem)

Both look similar to me. What exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the links you shared, and using Wikipedia's notation, Parseval assumes $A(x),B(x)$ are two square integrable (with respect to the Lebesgue measure), complex-valued functions on $\mathbb {R}$  of period $ 2\pi $  with Fourier series

$$A(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{inx}$$
and
$$B(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_ne^{inx}$$
Then 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\overline{b_n} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi A(x)\overline{B(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
[Plancherel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) provides a continuous version of Parsevals theorem (in a sense that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are now the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively and $A(x),B(x)$ are replaced by $ \widehat{f}(\xi), \widehat{g}(\xi)$)